# Google Sheets - Identify Duplicate Cells and Replace Cell Value App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, worksheet-function

Is there a way to identify duplicate cells and replace the duplicate's cell value to blank or clear it but not the entire row, only one column value. In my example below. I want to identify duplicates if Fruits and Item has the same value. In this case. Lime with item A and Apple with Item B are duplicates, and I want to replace Item duplicate value to blank.

| Fruits | Price | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lime | 1 | A |
| Apple | 2 | B |
| Lime | 3 | A |
| Apple | 2 | C |
| Apple | 4 | B |

I've got this code but it deletes the entire row. I only want to compare column A and C and should remove cell value in Column C and keep the first instance and not delete the row.

```
function removeDuplicates() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rng = sheet.getRange("A2:C")
var data = rng.getValues();
var newData = new Array();
for(i in data){
var row = data[i];
var duplicate = false;
for(j in newData){
  if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
    duplicate = true;
  }
}
if(!duplicate){
  newData.push(row);
}
}
rng.clearContent();
sheet.getRange(2, 1, newData.length, 
newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Here's the result that I want.

| Fruits | Price | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lime | 1 | A |
| Apple | 2 | B |
| Lime | 3 |  |
| Apple | 2 | C |
| Apple | 4 |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve your showing sample input and output situations using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, by `row.join() == newData[j].join()`, all values of columns "A", "B" and "C" are used. By this, the duplicated values of only columns "A" and "C" cannot be checked.
- And, in order to search the duplicated values, a loop is included in a loop. By this, I'm worried that the process cost will become high.
- In the case of `var rng = sheet.getRange("A2:C")`, all rows of the sheet are retrieved. In this case, the process cost will become high. So, you can use `var rng = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + sheet.getLastRow())`. By this, the data range is retrieved.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script 1:

In this pattern, your showing script is modified.

```js
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + sheet.getLastRow()); // Modified
  var data = rng.getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (j in newData) {
      if ([row[0] + row[2]].join() == [newData[j][0] + newData[j][2]].join()) { // Modified
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    } else {
      newData.push([row[0], row[1], null]); // Added
    }
  }
  rng.clearContent().setValues(newData); // Modified
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this pattern, only the duplicated cell values of column "C" are removed.

```js
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var { ranges } = data.reduce((o, [a, , c], i) => {
    var key = a + c;
    if (o.obj[key]) {
      o.ranges.push(`C${i + 2}`);
    } else {
      o.obj[key] = true;
    }
    return o;
  }, { ranges: [], obj: {} });
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).clearContent();
}
```

- When this script is run for your sample input situation, your sample output situation can be retrieved.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))

Comment: Awesome. The Modified script 2 worked perfectly well. Thank you. How can I edit this, I added columns in between, instead of A:C I have it as A:F. So, instead of C, duplicated cell values of column "F" should be removed. I did try to edit, but it doesn't seem to work. Can you help?

Comment: @coders_key Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your 2nd question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your 2nd question. So, in order to correctly understand your 2nd question, can you provide detailed information about it? By this, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand your 2nd question, I think that I can think of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional formatting where you set font color to white:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIFS(A$2:A&C$2:C, A2&C2, ROW(A$2:A), "<="&ROW(A2)))>1
```

[image]

Comment: I've got this conditional formatting. =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2, $A2, $C$2:$C2, $C2)>1 But I want to clear the duplicate value in Column C and keep the first instance. I think this is possible with App Script only.