# Change Cell Value on All But the Latest Entry

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Form supplying entries to a Google sheet, and I'm trying to change the value of all duplicate entries, not the newest. This will need to be run as Google Apps Script via a trigger. I'll be launching it every 5 or 10 minutes.

Here is how the sheet looks.

```
ColumnB           ColumnE       ColumnF
email@email.com   Individual    Weekly
email@email.com   Team          Weekly
email@email.com   Individual    Monthly
email@email.com   Team          Quarterly
```

In the above we have two duplicates, based on ColumnA+ColumnB (concatenated). I want to change the value of Column C to "None" for the earlier entries. This is what the resulting dataset should look like.

```
ColumnB           ColumnE       ColumnF
email@email.com   Individual    None
email@email.com   Team          None
email@email.com   Individual    Monthly
email@email.com   Team          Quarterly
```

If this code runs on a trigger every set x minutes then we really shouldn't see more than one set of duplicates. I'm also looking for a speedy solution as this form will continue to grow.

I have tried a loop through each row comparing columns A and B concatenated to all other rows (loop within a loop). Unfortunately, I this was beyond my expertise as I did not know how I would get the last entry to remain and change any entries before that one. This was the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73326907/google-sheets-identify-duplicate-cells-and-replace-cell-value-app-script) I tried following to no avail. The OP wanted to clear the cell for the duplicate on second occurrence. I needed to add "None" on any occurrence not the last.

Comment: Show what you have tried, describe the relevant questions that you found and why they don't meet your needs.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you Ruben. My apologies for not being clear enough. I've edited my post.

Comment: About `This was the post I tried following to no avail.`, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. From this situation, I proposed a modified script for achieving your goal as an answer. If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: No worries. I realize no one script covers all angles. I always try to adapt what I find out there but just couldn't figure it out. I'll check your solution out and let you know. I've selected an answer already but others will definitely appreciate the multiple methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  let uA = [];
  let o = vs.reverse().map((r, i) => {
    if (!~uA.indexOf(r[0] + r[1])) {
      uA.push(r[0] + r[1]);
      return [r[2]];
    } else {
      return ["none"];
    }
  }).reverse();
  sh.getRange(2,3,o.length,1).setValues(o);
}
```

Before:

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| email@email.com | Individual | Weekly |
| email@email.com | Team | Weekly |
| email@email.com | Individual | Monthly |
| email@email.com | Team | Quarterly |

After:

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| email@email.com | Individual | Weekly |
| email@email.com | Team | Weekly |
| email@email.com | Individual | none |
| email@email.com | Team | none |

Comment: Is this applying the changes to the last entries or is it applying it to the earlier entries and then flipping the order? I need to keep it in the order I have it in.

Comment: It should be the last two, “Monthly” and “Quarterly” that stays. The other two should be “none”

Comment: Ok. I applied a reverse to ```const [, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().reverse();``` and then another reverse to ```.setValues(o.reverse())``` and it worked. I did end up having to specify a range to not include the header because it was messing it up. It works now and it is nice and fast. 4 seconds to process about 7K lines. Would you mind making those edits to your post and then I'll accept your answer?

Comment: Let me ask this... is that the appropriate way to do it with the reverse? Am I violating some rule by doing that or is it bad code to do that? Is there a better solution?

Comment: If it works it's appropriate

Comment: Ok. I'm going to accept this as the answer. Thanks again. If you have time please edit it to correct for the order.

Answer (score 3):

From `This was the post I tried following to no avail.` in your question when my answer is modified as a sample, I thought that it might be useful for users including you. So, I proposed it. How about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const { ranges } = sheet
    .getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow())
    .getValues()
    .reduceRight((o, [a, b], i) =>
      (o.temp[a + b] ? o.ranges.push(`C${i + 2}`) : o.temp[a + b] = true, o)
      , { ranges: [], temp: {} });
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("None");
}
```

- In this modification, your goal is achieved by `reduceRight` and `RangeList`.

  - In the current stage, in the case of V8 runtime, `reduceRight` can be simply used. [Ref (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/08/03/important-reduceright-with-and-without-v8-runtime-for-google-apps-script/)
  - When the same value like "None" is put into multiple cells, I think that RangeList is useful.
- When this script is run to your sample input table, the sample output table can be obtained.

#### References:

- [reduceRight()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))

### Added:

About your following new situation and your updated question,

> This seems to be really fast but I can't figure out how to change it if my columns are not together like that. Let's say I have the email in column B and the team or individual on column E? I expanded the getRange to include B2:E. I'm just not familiar with how [a, d] works.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const { ranges } = sheet
    .getRange("A2:E" + sheet.getLastRow())
    .getValues()
    .reduceRight((o, [, b, , , e], i) =>
      (o.temp[b + e] ? o.ranges.push(`F${i + 2}`) : o.temp[b + e] = true, o)
      , { ranges: [], temp: {} });
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("None");
}
```

Comment: This seems to be really fast but I can't figure out how to change it if my columns are not together like that. Let's say I have the email in column B and the team or individual on column E? I expanded the getRange to include ```B2:E```. I'm just not familiar with how ```[a, d]``` works.

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for replying. About `This seems to be really fast but I can't figure out how to change it if my columns are not together like that. Let's say I have the email in column B and the team or individual on column E? I expanded the getRange to include B2:E. I'm just not familiar with how [a, d] works.`, in this case, do you want to change your showing sample input and output tables? If my understanding is correct, I can support you.

Comment: @DanCue But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot imagine your new situation. So, can you provide your new sample input and output tables? By this, I would like to modify my answer. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Ok. Changed the column letters to match what I have. I have a column number for each of these columns. I do a search for the header name and return a column number. So it would be nice to be able to insert a column number instead of a column letter.

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for replying. From your updated question, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: Excellent. That was less than 3 seconds for ~7K lines. Very efficient.

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for testing it. When the same value is put into multiple cells, the process cost of RangeList and setValue becomes low. For example, this my report might be useful. [Ref](https://medium.com/google-cloud/best-practices-for-discontinuous-cells-on-google-spreadsheet-by-google-apps-script-cef15b82f684)